# Adding Specific Array Values

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, addition

Ok, so I have an array.

```
var array = ['159','350','317','350','138','163','317','367','352','317'];
```

I want to loop through the array and take only specific values each time the loop runs and put these into another array.  E.g. taking every 3rd item in the array, so....

```
var a = 3;
var colArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  colArray[i] = [];
  for (var k = i; k < array.length; k += a) {
     colArray[i].push(array[k]);
  };    
}; 

console.log(colArray);
```

....would give this in the console on the first iteration.....

```
159, 350, 317, 317
```

All that works fine, but want I then want to do is add up the values in each array of `colArray`.  I DON'T want the total of each array, but want the 1st value to be added to 0, the 2nd to 0 + 1st and so on, to give something like this....

```
159, 509, 826, 1143
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4dr1wqc/)

Comment: why can't you keep a running total when you push to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, there is probably a better way to do it, but this worked for me.

```
  var array = ['159','350','317','350','138','163','317','367','352','317','159','138'];

var a = 3;
    var colArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      colArray[i] = [];

      for (var k = i; k < array.length; k += a) {
        if(k<a){
         colArray[i].push(Number(array[k]));
        }else{
         colArray[i].push(Number(array[k]) + Number(colArray[i][(k-a-i)/a]));
        }
      };    
    }; 

    console.log(colArray);
```